# Set arbitrary length mp3 as ringtone

Tags: iphone, ios, ringtones

Is it possible to circumvent the 40s limitation for iPhone ringtones?

If yes, how? Please suggest free or open source tools if possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I extend the iPhone's maximum ringtone duration?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5400/can-i-extend-the-iphones-maximum-ringtone-duration)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is unfortunately not possible to stretch the iPhone's ringtone for more than 40 seconds, as the iPhone's guidelines do not allow it.

Nevertheless, I read in a [German forum](https://qastack.com.de/apple/5400/can-i-extend-the-iphones-maximum-ringtone-duration) that it was possible up to iOS 10.3.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a set limit of 40 seconds for a ringtone file - anything longer and it will not sync.

However, this is moot because most carriers cannot go past this limit anyway.  For instance, AT&T allows you to [change the number up to 30 seconds](https://forums.att.com/conversations/samsung/how-to-change-the-number-of-rings-before-voicemail-answers-on-android-cellphones/612eada5d4dae759a2af59a0?commentId=612fcc58f82cbd1e76fca88b) (6 rings). This also applies to [Verizon](https://community.verizon.com/t5/Apple/Changing-number-of-rings-till-you-get-to-voicemail/m-p/235084/highlight/true#M46890).

I confirmed this with my carrier - 30 seconds is the maximum.